# "optimum" tree from random forests

Tags: r, random-forest, cart

You can get sample trees from random forest (e.g., see:
[How to actually plot a sample tree from randomForest::getTree()?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree))

However, rather than getting a single tree from random forest, is there any way to get an "optimum" or "recommended" tree which is generated considering the many trees?

Basically, I would like to replace decision tree models with random forest but would like to know what would be the best splits.

Comment: Related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72266/ideas-for-outputting-a-prediction-equation-for-random-forests

Comment: Closing as it is effectively point 2. of that other question and got no answers for quite a long time.